# seekTo(mTimeMilis) won't work properly when using ConcatenatingMediaSource in ExoPlayer

Tags: android, exoplayer2.x

I have more than one video to play one by one. After Creating MediaSource of each video, All these are going to `ConcatenatingMediaSource(mediaSources[])`. Normally it play one by one. But when video is fast forward using `seekTo()`, 1st video is ok but other videos do not follow `seekTo()`.

Suppose 1st video is 10s, 2nd 12s, 3rd 10s.
If I call `seekTo((long)12*1000)` it should play 2nd video with 2s forward. But it plays from the beginning of 2nd video.

Setting VideoSources

```
DefaultDataSourceFactory defaultDataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(getApplicationContext(),Util.getUserAgent(getApplicationContext(), "ExoPlayer"));
MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(defaultDataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(videoItem.getVideoUri());
videoItemArrayList.get(k).setVideoSource(mediaSource);
```

Concatenate Sources

```
MediaSource[] mediaSources = new MediaSource[videoItemArrayList.size()];
int j=0;
for(VideoItem item : videoItemArrayList){
    mediaSources[j] = item.getVideoSource();
    ++j;
}
concatenatedSource = new ConcatenatingMediaSource(mediaSources);
```

Setup exoplayer

```
exoPlayer.prepare(concatenatedSource);
exoPlayer.seekTo(0);
exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
exoPlayer.getPlaybackState();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `exoplayer.seekTo(period)` internally calls `currentWindowIndex()` internally of the source. While you are playing the first video in the concatenated mediasource you end up receiving `windowIndex` as 0. Use `seekTo(windowIndex, time)` to solve the issue.

Comment: Is it always guaranteed that for every media source in the concatenating media source there's a single window? so when I call seekTo(2, 3000), this will always play media source number 2 in the list ?